# "Package failed to install" error in KDE

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, software-updates

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and KDE Plasma 5.18.5. When I try to install system updates I get this error:

```
Package failed to install Error while installing package: cannot copy extracted data for 
'./boot/System.map-5.11.0-44-generic' to '/boot/System.map-5.11.0-44-generic.dpkg-new'
```

The /boot folder has these attributes if I do *ls -l /*:

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jan  5 08:42 boot
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Update with output from *df -h*:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2             705M  690M     0 100% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1             511M   86M  426M  17% /boot/efi
```

Comment: Check `df -h` output to see if your boot partition is full

Comment: @Panki I updated the question with the output. It seems that it is full. What is safe to delete in there to free up space?

Comment: As a first step, run `sudo apt autoremove`. If that doesn't get you far enough, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition

Comment: `apt-mark showmanual | grep 'linux-[g|h|i|m]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use discover for security fixes [there is a bug in packagekit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1914278)

```
   apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|i|m|h]' | egrep -v linux-generic-hwe-20.04 | xargs sudo apt-mark auto
```

then try

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```